# Will Philly the Kid die when he'll have no more skin to be tattooed?

Tags: cannon-busters

Philly the Kid is the main character of the original net anime, *Cannon Busters* ([YouTube trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6IsyIsZSXwU)), who has tattoos on his body.

Will Philly the Kid die when he'll have no more skin to be tattooed? What will happen then? Will he die permanently?

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think his curse is based off of how much skin he has left to be tattooed, I don’t have a great reason as to why, outside of the fact that he doesn’t really seem to care that his death count nearly doubled in the events of season 1. I know that Philly usually is pretty rash and irresponsible, but I doubt he wouldn’t at least bat an eye if he thought there was a chance he could permanently die soon.

Since it looks like he’s been aging since he first got his immortality, I’d say his best bet at death is dying of old age.

Comment: I agree with most of what has been said about Philly's curse, but I don't believe he can die of old age either. He makes many comments about being immortal and about not wanting to spend his immortality in certain ways which leads to a conclusion that he will live forever.